# UIWebview reload doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, reload

I use `UIWebView` to load the remote url, the page is blank because the network is unavailable. After network is available ,i reload the `UIWebView`, but the page is still blank.

How can i solve it?

Comment: try to load that `url` in browser to check whether its loading to not.

Comment: reload() can‘t load the url；loadRequest() can work，but it will lead to other problems

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    func reloadRequest() {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url);
            self.loadRequest(request);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Load web view with request again, like:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            wvWebView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Here is sample code.

```
@IBOutlet var wvWebView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        wvWebView.delegate = self
        reloadWebview()
}


// call this function to reload web view.
func reloadWebview(){  
     if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            wvWebView.loadRequest(request)
     }
}

// Webview Delegates
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        print("\n\n**** webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: \(request.url) \(navigationType)")
        return true
}


func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print("webViewDidStartLoad")
}


func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print("webViewDidFinishLoad")
}

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
    print("error description - \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```